# An exercise using Lagrange's Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having some trouble finding the max and min of the below problem  using Lagrange multipliers:

$$ f(x,y) = x^2 -2xy + 3y^2 \\ \text{subject to} \ \  x^2 + 2y^2 + x + y = 0$$

Is there a trick or something i am missing? that was a question in one of my friends test and no one was able to solve it.

--------------------------------------------------------//--------------------------------------------------------

i get:

$$ 2x-2y = \lambda(2x+1) \\ -2x+6y = \lambda(4y+1) \\  x^2 + 2y^2 + x + y = 0$$

i can't solve it, is there a shortcut?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Did you compute the partial derivatives? Could you solve the system of equations obtained?

Comment: i am stuck at the system of equations

Comment: Yes, you should revise the rules of derivation.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz  i just did

Comment: @A. Pongrácz i divided by 2 does it matter? the vectors just need to have the same direction right?

Comment: Of course it matters. Why do incorrect tricks like that when you are having issues solving the problem?

Comment: No, you haven't just divided by $2$. Your derivation is not correct.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz how about now?

Comment: It is good now.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz Am i incorrect? i believed that the theorem was equivalent to say that both gradients are parallel, thats why i divided by 2 before using the lambdas in the equation.

Comment: I don't know where you get this idea from, but think about it for a moment: you basically say that it doesn't matter if you divide ONE SIDE of the equations by any nonzero real numbers... How do you expect to obtain equivalent systems of equations? If you divide both sides by $2$, then fine, but only dividing the left hand side cannot be correct.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz i am not saying i get the same lambdas but the same candidates for x and y, thats my question.

Comment: Absolutely not. Think about it! And again: "i believed that the theorem was equivalent to say that both gradients are parallel" where did you get this idea from? Could you point out a reference? (In mathematics, if you claim something, you are the one who has to provide the evidence. It is not my job to disprove your claim, but yours to prove it.)

Comment: @A. Pongrácz  thank you

Comment: @RobertWilliamHanks: I added a solution below. It is rather tedious, but I see no obvious simplification that would yield an easier path.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for real solutions.

The Lagrangian function is:
$$
L(x,y,\lambda)= x^2-2xy + 3y^2-\lambda(x^2+2y^2+x+y)
$$

Taking derivatives with respect to $x, y, \lambda$ respectively yields:
$$
2x-2y -2\lambda x -\lambda=0$$

$$-2x+6y-4 \lambda y -\lambda = 0$$

$$x^2+2y^2+x+y=0$$

To solve the system (three equations, three unknowns), note that:
$\lambda = \frac{2x-2y}{2x+1} = \frac{-2x+6y}{4y+1}$. Therefore:
$$
(2x-2y)(1+4y) = (2x+1) (6y-2x)
$$
or
$$
4x^2-8y^2-4xy+4x-8y=0 \,(I)
$$
Multiplying the constraint by 4 gives:
$$4x^2 + 8y^2 + 4x + 4y=0.  \, (II)$$

Deducting (I) from (II) yields:

$$16y^2 + 4xy +12y=0$$

Therefore, either $y=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ or $x=-1$, or $16y+4x+12=0$. Combine the last equation with the constraint to find additional solutions, and you will get none (they are complex). 
So there are two solutions for $(x,y)$, namely $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$

You should check also the second order conditions at the optimum, e.g. bordered Hessian, or KKT conditions.

Plugging these values into the objective function gives: $f(0,0)=0$, $f(-1,0)=3$. The point (0,0) is a minimum; (-1,0) is a maximum.

Comment: I think the conclusion is a bit hasty. Just like in case of univariate functions, just because the derivative is zero at $x$, it doesn't mean that $x$ is any kind of extremal point.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually, the author of the post is very unclear about where his problems arose. He made mistakes in finding the equations as well, so this answer is clearly helpful. I see that pendermath has extended the answer; but the problem I pointed out is still valid. It is not clear at all if the two points you have found are extremal or not. And the fact that $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(-1,0)=3$ does not imply that the former is a minimum and the latter is a maximum. It could be the other way around, or it could be that some of these are not even local extrema.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz: The author has added an elaboration.

Comment: @copper.hat But it is still not addressing my problem.

Comment: Sorry, but the "Therefore" part in the end is still absurd.

Comment: Does using Hessian makes any sense in this kinds of problems? is there a simple way to test if the points found are max or min?

Comment: At this point I suggest that you revisit the theory. Confer a textbook.

Comment: ok thank you both

Answer (score 1):

The constraint defines a compact set so we know a solution exists.

The Lagrange equations are
$E_1:2x-2y+ \lambda (1+2x) = 0$,
$E_2: 6y-2x + \lambda (1+4y) = 0$.

Simplifying the equation $(1+4y)E_1-(1+2x)E_2 = 0$ gives
$(1+x+y)(2y-x) = 0$.

If we let $y=-(1+x)$ in the constraint we get $(x+1)(3x+1) = 0$ which yields
the candidates $(-1,0), (-{1 \over 3} , -{2 \over 3})$. A tedious computation shows that
$f$ has value $1$ at both points.

If we let $x=2y$ in the constraint we get  $y(2y+1) = 0$ which yields the candidates
$(0,0),(-1, -{1 \over 2})$. Another computation shows that $f$ has value $0, {3 \over 4}$ respectively from which we see that
the $\min$ is $0$ at $(0,0)$ and the $\max$ is $1$ at either $(-1,0), (-{1 \over 3} , -{2 \over 3})$.

**Notes**:

Note that the quadratic form $f(x,y)$ is positive definite and that $(0,0)$
satisfies the constraint. Hence $(0,0)$ is a (in fact, the) minimiser since $f(0,0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from pendermath's answer, considering the equations
$$2x-2y -2\lambda x -\lambda=0\tag1$$

$$-2x+6y-4 \lambda y -\lambda = 0\tag2$$

$$x^2+2y^2+x+y=0\tag3$$ solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $x$ and $y$. This gives
$$x=-\frac{\lambda }{2 \lambda -1}\qquad \text{and} \qquad y=-\frac{\lambda }{2 (2 \lambda -1)}=\frac x 2$$ assuming $\lambda \neq \frac 12$.

Plug in $(3)$ to get
$$\frac{3 (\lambda -1) \lambda }{2 (2 \lambda-1 )^2}=0$$ so the candidates $\lambda=0$ for which $x=y=0$ and $\lambda=1$ for which $x=-1$ and $y=\frac 12$

Comment: I think you are missing a minus sign on the last y.